# MATLAB - Creating changing row titles within for loop that can be used as Matrix row labels

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to creating a table from a matrix within a for loop.

The problem I am having is creating a label for the rows that adds a new row each time the loop progresses. The code works for the first loop, and RLABEL updates itself for the 2nd loop but then when I come to print the matrix it says that there isn't enough row labels.

I was just wondering whether there was a way of MATLAB reading that there are 2 row labels from RLABEL without having to input them all manually each time?

Below is a copy of my code

```
d = 2;           
kij = [1,2];       
uMatrix = zeros(1:2);    
for j=1:d        
     RLABEL(j,:) = ['Row','',int2str(j)]   %Creates Row string that updates itself each loop
     Px = rand                          
     var = (5/12)*d*sum(kij)             
     lam = 1/sqrt(var)                  
     u(j) = ((log(1-Px))/-lam)+kij(1,j)    
     uMatrix(j,1) = j;  
     uMatrix(j,2) = u(j)
     printmat(uMatrix,'Results',RLABEL,'SECTION u' )    
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row labels need to in a single string separated by spaces. Furthermore, note that the line with `printmat` should be placed outside the loop:

```
d = 2;
kij = [1,2];
uMatrix = zeros(1:2);

RLABEL=[];
for j=1:d

    RLABEL= [RLABEL 'Row','',int2str(j) ' '];   %Creates Row string that updates itself each loop

    Px = rand
    var = (5/12)*d*sum(kij)
    lam = 1/sqrt(var)
    u(j) = ((log(1-Px))/-lam)+kij(1,j)

    uMatrix(j,1) = j;

    uMatrix(j,2) = u(j)
end

printmat(uMatrix,'Results',RLABEL,'SECTION u' )
```

This results in

```
Results = 
                   SECTION            u
         Row1      1.00000      3.21609
         Row2      2.00000      2.22374
```